# angular-translate translate in translation file

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is it possible to pass a variable into a translation file, and have it translated inside the translation file?

// translation.json

```
"country":{
    "CHINA":"中国",
    "US":"United States"
}

"text":"I live in $translate('country.{{country}}'), {{ someOtherVar }}.
```

Comment: Would you let us know the reason why **don't** you want to translate the sentence "I live in..."(it's obviously English) even for Chinese user?

Comment: The Chinese translation file will be in chinese for the "I live in..." part. The issue is that the country name is coming from an object property that is in English i.e., { country:"CHINA" } When iterating over these country objects the country name needs to be translated to the user's selected language. So, I don't want "我住在 CHINA" and I don't want a key for every country.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Do you mean "I live in..." part always don't need to be translated even if the user's selected language is Chinese? If you mean so, why don't you write "I live in..." part simply on your HTML instead of translation.json?

Comment: No, The whole sentence will be translated to whatever the user has selected. {{ Tom }} lives in {{ US }}, {{ Lee }} lives in {{ China }} -> {{ Tom }} 住在 {{ 美国 }}, {{ Lee }} 住在 {{ 中国 }}.

Comment: I gradually understood what you want to achieve, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this structure below would help for you to achieve what you want.

In the English translation file

```
"country": {
    "CHINA": "China",
    "US": "United States",
    ...
},
"text":"I live in {{country}}, {{ someOtherVar }}."
```

In the Chinese translation file

```
"country": {
    "CHINA": "中国",
    "US": "美国",
    ...
},
"text":"我住在{{country}}, {{ someOtherVar }}."
```

In HTML

```
<span translate="text" translate-values="{country: translated_country_name, someOtherVar: someothervar}"></span>
```

In controller

```
$scope.someothervar = // some value
var countrykey = //CHINA or US...
$translate('country.' + countrykey).then(function(trans){
    $scope.translated_country_name = trans;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always preprocess the translation file (e.g. by `$httpProvider.interceptors`).

But you have the `country` variable available for you from (probably) the scope.
So you should write something like this:

```
var country = ...;
country = $translate(country);
$scope.translatedText = $translate('text', { country: country, someOtherVar: 'value' });
```

where your `text` should be:

```
"text":"I live in {{country}}, {{ someOtherVar }}."
```

Here you've got the documentation for [dynamic translation](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Dynamize-your-translations).